# Converting Linux Date -r output to DateTime

Tags: c#, linux, date, datetime, unix

I need to convert the output of a "date -r" command to DateTime for parsing purposes.
The output is this one:

```
Fri Aug 6 15:40:55 2021
```

I'm trying to create a string variabile and converting it to DateTime but I'm always getting a

```
"System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
  + System.DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, System.IFormatProvider)"
```

This is my code:

```
string date = "Fri Aug 6 15:40:55 CEST 2021";
date = date.Replace(" CEST", ""); // removing not needed info
string date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "D MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

Am I missing the format? Are there any easier/better ways to convert this to DateTime or string?

Comment: This format of date is VERY bad for inputting into a program, as it will change depending on the locale of the PC that is running the code.    If you need to know the current date/time, just call `DateTime.UtcNow`.  If you REALLY want to use date, then use `date --iso-8601`, which will output UTC in the universal ISO8601 format.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using REFERENCE (-r) since I need to compare the last modified time of a file to current system time. Anyway many thanks for the help, I'll surely use those if I'd need again.

Comment: How about using `FileSystemInfo` to get the date of the file? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo?view=net-5.0#properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abbreviated name of the day of the week shall be "ddd", not "D".
Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Thanks, now I got it! Th correct format should be set as "string date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();". Since the day could also include an empty space I'll just need to use a Try, catch and I should be able to make it work. Thanks :)